# Resource Compiler question (initially posed as "UAC together with Subst don't work well together")

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, resources

I am trying to run VS2010 with UAC on.  ResourceCompiler complains that it cannot find a file located on a subst'ed drive.

Here's a fusion log.

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry (8/16/2010 @ 1:54:39 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable P:\io\bin\common\FireFly.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User =========
LOG: DisplayName = MyAssembly.resources, Version=2.2.2.23024, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///P:/io/bin/common/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MyApp.exe
Calling assembly : MyAssembly, Version=2.2.2.23024, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: P:\io\bin\common\MyApp.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file:
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
ERR: Unrecoverable error occurred during pre-download check (hr = 0x80070002).
```

What would you recommend?

Comment: If UAC is turned off, the error goes away.  From what I can see, it's a funky new behavior amongst {UAC, ResourceCompiler, Subst}

Comment: Asked the same question on 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586646/the-generateresource-task-failed-unexpectedly

Comment: I honestly didn't know anyone used subst anymore.  I don't think I've seen it used since DOS 6.22

Comment: It's pretty ingrained in our current build system.  It would be nice if this worked well.

Comment: Something to ponder...  When you get a BadImageFormatException, does it mean:
a) You have a bad bitmap picture in resource file
b) You have a x86 vs. x64 issue?

Comment: I tried to change pictures and it worked.  One TIFF resource compiler likes, and another one -- doesn't.  Beats me.

Comment: I have uploaded a section of resource file that is responsible for this at Microsoft Connect site mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to change pictures and it worked. One TIFF resource compiler likes, and another one -- doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

WhereWith UAC on, I'm betting the process runs in a different security context, that doesn't have access, or doesn't know about the p: drive.  Use [Microsoft TechNet's Sysinternals Procmon.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor the activation (searching and loading of dependent dlls).

Sxstrace.exe can also be helpful in tracking down assembly activation problems.

Comment: Even though it may be remotely relevant to the question asked, this does not propose a solution.  In fact, it's likely a Microsoft bug.